# Как изменить php код wp_nav_menu для изменения html разметки?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Есть меню, которое построено с помощью функции wp_nav_menu. Из одного пункта выпадает sub-menu.
Требуется сделать так, чтоб в одном из li-элементов появился input, а за ним input.
те выглядеть оно должно так:

```
<ul>
  <li><a></a></li>
  <li>
   <a></a>
   <input type="checkbox" name="toggle" id="menuBox" class="toggleMenu">
   <label for="menuBox" class="toggleMenu"></label>
   <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
   </ul>     
  </li>
  <li><a></a></li>
  <li><a></a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте хук [wp_nav_menu_items](https://wp-kama.ru/hook/wp_nav_menu_items). С его помощью вы получите полный html код меню и сможете внести в него необходимые изменения через строковые функции.